# How can I stream an OpenCV video?

Tags: javascript, python, opencv, websocket, video-streaming

I'm trying to make the image/video streaming from [here](https://github.com/pornpasok/opencv-stream-video-to-web) work on socket so I could make it send that stream to a server in the cloud. For testing, I just use `Live Server` to host the webpage and use `websocket` as the mechanism for transferring the data. I was able to make something show on the webpage, but it seems like it only shows the first frame the camera got after I ran my code. The webpage does seem to be getting more frames but I did notice that they seem to look the same. Then I stumbled upon `cv2.imshow()` and I does seem to be that `VideoStream` isn't giving a new frame/image, but if I ran the code from source repo, everything works fine.

Here's what I have so far, I'll only add the parts that I changed/added:

```py
async def generate():
    ...
    # yield (b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' +
    #        bytearray(encodedImage) + b'\r\n')
    yield encodedImage.tobytes()
```

I made a main.py with:

```py
import argparse
import asyncio
import threading
import aioschedule as schedule

from webstreaming import detect_motion
from socket_helper import socket_serve

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    # construct the argument parser and parse command line arguments
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-i", "--ip", type=str, required=True,
                    help="ip address of the device")
    ap.add_argument("-o", "--port", type=int, required=True,
                    help="ephemeral port number of the server (1024 to 65535)")
    ap.add_argument("-f", "--frame-count", type=int, default=32,
                    help="# of frames used to construct the background model")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())
    # start a thread that will perform motion detection
    t = threading.Thread(target=detect_motion, args=(
        args["frame_count"],))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(socket_serve())
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

I made a socket helper as well:

    import time
    import websockets
    from websockets.sync.client import connect
    from webstreaming import generate

    HOST_NAME = "localhost"
    SOCKET_PORT = 15000
    wsConn = any

    async def stream_cam_handler(websocket):
        print(f"stream_cam_handler")
        async for frame in generate():
            time.sleep(0.2)
            await websocket.send(frame)

    async def handler(websocket, path):
        global wsConn
        wsConn = websocket

        data = await websocket.recv()
        reply = f"Data received as:  {data}!"

        await websocket.send(reply)

        await stream_cam_handler(websocket)


    def socket_serve():
        start_server = websockets.serve(handler, "localhost", 15000)
        return start_server
```

Then here's what I got for the webpage:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pi Video Surveillance</h1>
    <img id="img_vid_feed" src="/" alt="video_feed">
    <br>

    <script>
        let image = document.getElementById("img_vid_feed");
        const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:15000');
        ws.binaryType = "blob";
 
        ws.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
            ws.send('Connection Established');
        });

        ws.onmessage = function (event) {
            image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.data);
        };
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not an opencv problem. you say your code does work on one system but not the other. describe that in more detail? you didn't provide a [mre]. you should want others to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Well, I feel like it is an opencv question, because that's the source of the data that I want to stream. I already added my code, what more reproducible example do I need to give? I don't get it

Comment: does the source of the data matter to the error you're getting? if you replaced all the videocapture stuff by just generating a black picture with, say, a timestamp drawn into it with `putText`, does that change anything or does the issue still happen? -- your code lacks file names (`webstreaming`...), there is code missing in the `generate()` function, and so on

Comment: @minaj What is the content of **frame** in `await websocket.send(frame)`? If it's a byte array, then make sure the first three array slot values are ALWAYS **255**, **216**, **255** and then also confirm that the last two array slot values are **255**, **217**. That makes it correct JPEG data that is acceptable to the `<img>` tag in HTML5. PS: I don't use Python, so I'm not sure what `b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n'` is doing here but just know that your socket must not send Strings to the image tag (in case some text like _"Content-Type: image/jpeg"_ is being added to the sent data).

Comment: OP is mixing the "regular" content-replace stuff that sends those multi-part content pieces... with websockets, sending unframed files. OP has a lot of things to pin down.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz have you checked the repo I linked above(https://github.com/pornpasok/opencv-stream-video-to-web)? The reason why I didn't add all the code is because I didn't touch most of them. So what's happening is I seem to be getting a new image in js but only the added timestamp by generate() (please look at the repo for more info) gets updated. I don't think it's an error, I think I have to do something with opencv or VideoStream to fix the issue

Comment: My previous title perfectly summarizes what I wanted to do. I wanted to stream the results of OpenCV to some sort of socket so I can point it to a server that can listen to said stream. Or I there's a different mechanism I could use, please show me and I'll try it out. My project is already using UDP that's why I thought maybe I could do the streaming there.